# How to rename DNS account of my Office 365 SharePoint External Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, office

I have a Domain site from 1&1 , and i successfully configured it with office 365, but after that I'm not able to rename my site with the new domain?

Could someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried following this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Rename-your-SharePoint-Online-Public-Website-address-to-use-your-custom-domain-3d4bd288-772b-4f88-af4d-f025b3825ed3 . At which step are you failing? What is the error/message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Log into Office 365 admin, select SharePoint at left menu, click 'Site collections', select public your site & press `Rename Website` at the Ribbon. It only gets activated if it's public website, not usual *.sharepoint.com

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the actual tenancy, that is 'example.sharepoint.com', this cannot be renamed. You would have to purchase a brand new O365 tenant and migrate all content over to the new tenant.